# Azure Function (.NET 7 Isolated) create an Azure Function App targeting .NET6?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-7.0

Today I deployed a new Azure `Function App` targeting `.NET 7 Isolated` as framework on Azure. To create the resource on Azure I used the wizard present on `Visual Studio 2022`, so I both created the new resource and deployed it using `VS2022`.
Going to view the `Function App` on Azure, I realized that the wizard created it by running it over the `.NET 6 stack` although it also offers me the `Isolated .NET7 stack`:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a specific technical reason and possibly if it is safe to switch to `.NET6` from the `.NET7 Isolated stack`.

Comment: Is there any issues running the azure function app currently?

Comment: @thanzeel no, the function works perfectly, for that I thought there was a specific reason

Comment: Okay then, as far as i know the `in proc` function apps supports stuff likE `IAyncCollector` and other bindings which are not available in the isolated model yet. But from dotnet 7 and ahead the support for `in proc` is discontinued. Its best to stick to isolated function apps

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I have observed the same in my environment as below:

In my local Environment its `.net 7` :

[image]

When I publish it to Azure its Changed to `.net 6`:

[image]

You can change there to `.net 7` if any functionality doesn't work in `. net 6` in portal:

[image]

I have also tried to create a .net 7 function app while creating portal:

[image]

I have observed that after creating its showing `.net7`
and when i deploy to this function app after deploying its showing `.net6`.
So, after deploying its changing to .net6. I would suggest if any functionality does not work, you can change to `.net 7` manually.

Comment: exactly, in fact when I created function app on Azure I noticed that with the configuration of the stack to `.net7`, when you then go to deploy the project via vs2022 you even get a prompt that tells you "for a correct deploy we have to change the runtime of the function on Azure" (roughly), which obviously doesn't happen when doing everything via vs2022. Actually the function I developed seems to me to be working quite well on that stack, so I think I'll keep it like this for now, trying to document myself better

Comment: yeah you are right

Comment: @Surya As can be seen from the answer, it simply reproduced my case. If you want, I'll put the symbol of accepted answer but in fact no one has ever actually answered my question.